Openvpn Routes are not adding to the server when client is connecting
Can't find out why routes are not adding.
tail -f openvpn.log | grep kostro
2024-06-26 11:59:22 kostroma/85.26.211.200:55610 SIGTERM[soft,delayed-exit] received, client-instance exiting
2024-06-26 11:59:23 85.26.211.200:58054 VERIFY OK: depth=0, CN=kostroma
2024-06-26 11:59:23 85.26.211.200:58054 [kostroma] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]85.26.211.200:58054
2024-06-26 11:59:23 kostroma/85.26.211.200:58054 MULTI_sva: pool returned IPv4=192.168.200.3, IPv6=(Not enabled)
2024-06-26 11:59:23 kostroma/85.26.211.200:58054 OPTIONS IMPORT: reading client specific options from: /etc/openvpn/ccd/kostroma
2024-06-26 11:59:23 kostroma/85.26.211.200:58054 MULTI: Learn: 192.168.200.38 -> kostroma/85.26.211.200:58054
2024-06-26 11:59:23 kostroma/85.26.211.200:58054 MULTI: primary virtual IP for kostroma/85.26.211.200:58054: 192.168.200.38
2024-06-26 11:59:23 kostroma/85.26.211.200:58054 MULTI: internal route 10.1.0.0/16 -> kostroma/85.26.211.200:58054
2024-06-26 11:59:23 kostroma/85.26.211.200:58054 MULTI: Learn: 10.1.0.0/16 -> kostroma/85.26.211.200:58054
2024-06-26 11:59:23 kostroma/85.26.211.200:58054 MULTI: internal route 10.1.4.0/24 -> kostroma/85.26.211.200:58054
2024-06-26 11:59:23 kostroma/85.26.211.200:58054 MULTI: Learn: 10.1.4.0/24 -> kostroma/85.26.211.200:58054
2024-06-26 11:59:23 kostroma/85.26.211.200:58054 MULTI: internal route 10.1.3.0/24 -> kostroma/85.26.211.200:58054
2024-06-26 11:59:23 kostroma/85.26.211.200:58054 MULTI: Learn: 10.1.3.0/24 -> kostroma/85.26.211.200:58054
2024-06-26 11:59:23 kostroma/85.26.211.200:58054 MULTI: internal route 10.1.0.0/24 -> kostroma/85.26.211.200:58054
2024-06-26 11:59:23 kostroma/85.26.211.200:58054 MULTI: Learn: 10.1.0.0/24 -> kostroma/85.26.211.200:58054
2024-06-26 11:59:23 kostroma/85.26.211.200:58054 Data Channel: using negotiated cipher 'AES-128-GCM'
2024-06-26 11:59:23 kostroma/85.26.211.200:58054 Outgoing Data Channel: Cipher 'AES-128-GCM' initialized with 128 bit key
2024-06-26 11:59:23 kostroma/85.26.211.200:58054 Incoming Data Channel: Cipher 'AES-128-GCM' initialized with 128 bit key
2024-06-26 11:59:23 kostroma/85.26.211.200:58054 SENT CONTROL [kostroma]: 'PUSH_REPLY,topology subnet,dhcp-option DNS 172.16.10.1,dhcp-option DNS 172.16.10.2,route 172.16.10.0 255.255.255.0,route 172.16.11.0 255.255.255.0,route 172.22.22.0 255.255.255.0,route-gateway 192.168.200.1,topology subnet,ping 10,ping-restart 60,ifconfig 192.168.200.38 255.255.255.0,peer-id 4,cipher AES-128-GCM' (status=1)

ip r
default via 172.16.10.254 dev ens18 proto static
172.16.2.0/24 via 172.16.10.81 dev ens18 proto static
172.16.10.0/24 dev ens18 proto kernel scope link src 172.16.10.177
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1
192.168.188.0/24 via 172.16.10.254 dev ens18 proto static
192.168.189.0/24 via 172.16.10.254 dev ens18 proto static
192.168.200.0/24 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.200.1

Why there is no routes from /etc/openvpn/ccd/kostroma ? Is it because of (status=1) ? (status=1) it is bad ?
Thank
Here's my configs
cat /etc/openvpn/ccd/kostroma
ifconfig-push 192.168.200.38 255.255.255.0
iroute 10.1.0.0 255.255.255.0
iroute 10.1.3.0 255.255.255.0
iroute 10.1.4.0 255.255.255.0
iroute 10.1.0.0 255.255.0.0

cat /etc/openvpn/server.conf
...
route 10.1.0.0 255.255.255.0
route 10.1.3.0 255.255.255.0
route 10.1.4.0 255.255.255.0
route 10.1.0.0 255.255.0.0
user root
group root
...

